# Micronaut HTTP Client handeling empty parameters in GET requests

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-client, http-parameters

Micronaut declarative HTTP Client question

I need to construct a GET request that looks like this:

```
URL/index?xxx=42&singledatapoint&Unadjusted
```

If I use MN’s declarative HTTP Client, like this:

```
@Get('/index?no={number}&singledatapoint&Unadjusted')
HttpResponse<String> getData(int number)
```

The final URL looks like this:

```
URL/index?no=42&singledatapoint=&Unadjusted=
```

MN has added `=` (equal signs) to the end of the empty parameters.

This fails with a invalid request on the server.

I tried the following permutations with the same sad results:

```
URL/index?no=42&singledatapoint=””&Unadjusted=””
URL/index?no=42&singledatapoint=null&Unadjusted=null
```

**My question:** How do I force MN to stop putting `=` (equal sign) after the empty parameters?

*Please note:
The receiving server (on which I have no control) for the request does not accept the `=` that is why I need it removed.*

**Code**

```
@MarketData
@Client('https://someurl')
interface MarketDataClient {

    @Get('/index?no={number}&singledatapoint&Unadjusted')
    HttpResponse<String> getData(int number)

}

@MarketData
@Filter(MATCH_ALL_PATTERN)
class MarketDataFilter implements HttpClientFilter {

    @Override
    Publisher<? extends HttpResponse<?>> doFilter(MutableHttpRequest<?> request, ClientFilterChain chain) {
        //NO WORKY!
        request.parameters.add('singledatapoint', null) //MN ignores the parameter
        request.parameters.add('Unadjusted', '') //gives the '='
        chain.proceed(request)
    }

}

@FilterMatcher
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target([TYPE, PARAMETER])
@interface MarketData { }
```

Comment: Can you add the source of the declarative client to the question? One way to solve this problem is to use a Micronaut client filter and add the additional property key in that filter (see https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#clientFilter)

Comment: FYI... https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/discussions/4849

Comment: @saw303 No matter how I add the parameter, I cannot make the '=' go away

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I'm not sure what you're hinting at?